# Scheduled silent mode on S3

Tags: automation

Got a Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2  Some time ago it started changing my phone to silent mode
automatically, every evening at 19:30. I did not install any scheduler app, nor did I change any settings. How can I find this setting and remove it?

Comment: Some devices have a corresponding section in the system settings, called "Silent times" or similar. Not having an S3, I cannot tell you where Samsung might have put that -- but you might simply browse through the system settings and watch our for something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Select System Settings, then turn off Blocking Mode (under the Device heading). You (or someone!) might have accidentally pressed that button when scrolling down the list.   You could go into it first and confirm that the 'set time' is 19:30; if not then the problem is something else.